# Why is this F/A-18 flying through a hailstorm of sparkles?

Tags: cockpit, night-flying, fa-18

The [F/A-18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet) Super Hornet squadron [VF-102 Diamondbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VFA-102), flying from the [USS Ronald Reagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Ronald_Reagan), has posted a [montage video](https://youtu.be/H6yKt28tVJg) of its 2019 Indo-China cruise.

At about 5:15, [the video](https://youtu.be/H6yKt28tVJg) shows a night-time cockpit view of the aircraft flying through a shower of sparks. There is also the view looking backwards. It's like a sci-fi special-effect.

What would cause this phenomenon?

[image: Youtube F-18]
<sub>[source - YouTube](https://youtu.be/H6yKt28tVJg)</sub>

Comment: Illuminated rain drops appear almost horizontal due to the speed ?

Comment: That's what it looks like when you light the afterburner and go into hyperspace.

Comment: Flying thru rain or snow at night with landing lights on totally gives the sci-fi "warp speed" effect looking forward. Dunno about the part looking aft. The segment is playing at many X normal speed. Might just be rain drops in the aircraft's red lights, but that's only a guess.

Comment: Is that scene of the video in real speed or time-lapse?

Comment: Jorg, Ralph - I think Jpe61 is correct about it being gunfire residue so no the video isn't speeded up. You can see something very similar here https://www.popularmechanics.com/flight/a23060/super-hornet-cannons-hyperspace/

Comment: My God, it's full of stars!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The sparks in the video come from the F-18's Vulcan cannon being fired at night.

During daytime you'd only see muzzle flash accompanied by a pretty puff of smoke. Low light conditions bring out the sparks, or rather, residual gunpowder still burning (or glowing) as it exits the barrel.

Comment: Interesting - looks spectacular. I remember seeing this documentary about the [St Elmo's fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Elmo%27s_fire) experienced on [BA Flight 9, June 24, 1982](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0xmWqYgtis). Also very strange to look at. [Air Craft Investigations / Mayday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mayday_episodes) - [Season 4, Episode 2 (2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mayday_episodes#Season_4_(2007)).